# Android - Data Persist between fragments for common entity

Tags: android, entity

I have common entity between two fragments , when I move between fragments I pass it in bundle and when i make changes on the fragment and when I go back without saving value are persist in the previous  entity

Comment: what is your question?

Comment: HI,
Question is how to prevent this from being persist values in fragment

Answer (score 0):

**Try this,**

> 1. Create `MainActivity` class where your `fragments` are going to place

```
public class MainActivity extends AppCompatActivity implements MainActivityHelperInterface{

    private FrameLayout fragmentContainer;
    private ArrayList<Integer> dataList;
    android.support.v4.app.FragmentManager fragmentManager;

    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);

        initViews();

        initObjects();

        // add 1st fragment
        fragmentManager.beginTransaction().add(R.id.fragmentContainer,new FirstFragment()).addToBackStack("firstFragment").commit();


        // your code and condition when you want to load second one

        fragmentManager.beginTransaction().add(R.id.fragmentContainer,new SecondFragment()).addToBackStack("secondFragment").commit();


    }

    private void initObjects() {
        dataList = new ArrayList<>();
        fragmentManager = getSupportFragmentManager();
        // here your data
        // or server data
        for (int index = 0 ; index < 10; index ++)
            dataList.add(index);
    }

    private void initViews() {
        fragmentContainer = (FrameLayout)findViewById(R.id.fragmentContainer);
    }

    // set data from any fragment
    @Override
    public void setData(ArrayList<Integer> dataSet) {
        this.dataList = dataSet;
    }

    @Override
    public ArrayList<Integer> getData() {
        return dataList;
    }

    @Override
    public void addEntry(int data) {
        dataList.add(data);
    }

    @Override
    public void removeEntry(int index) {
        dataList.remove(index);
    }
}
```

> 2. Create `FirstFragment` class

```
public class FirstFragment extends Fragment{

    private MainActivityHelperInterface mainActivityHelperInterface;
    private ArrayList<Integer> dataList;

    @Override
    public void onAttach(Context context) {
        super.onAttach(context);
        mainActivityHelperInterface = (MainActivityHelperInterface) context;
    }

    @Nullable
    @Override
    public View onCreateView(LayoutInflater inflater, @Nullable ViewGroup container, @Nullable Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        //here inflate your view
        View view = inflater.inflate(R.layout.first_fragment,null);

        mainActivityHelperInterface.addEntry(2);
        mainActivityHelperInterface.removeEntry(2);
        dataList = mainActivityHelperInterface.getData();

        mainActivityHelperInterface.setData(dataList);


        //your code
        return view;
    }
}
```

> 3. create `SecondFragment` class

```
public class SecondFragment extends Fragment {
    private MainActivityHelperInterface mainActivityHelperInterface;
    private ArrayList<Integer> dataList;


    @Override
    public void onAttach(Context context) {
        super.onAttach(context);
        mainActivityHelperInterface = (MainActivityHelperInterface) context;
    }

    @Nullable
    @Override
    public View onCreateView(LayoutInflater inflater, @Nullable ViewGroup container, @Nullable Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        //here inflate your view
        View view = inflater.inflate(R.layout.second_fragment,null);

        mainActivityHelperInterface.addEntry(2);
        mainActivityHelperInterface.removeEntry(2);
        dataList = mainActivityHelperInterface.getData();

        mainActivityHelperInterface.setData(dataList);

        //your code
        return view;
    }
}
```

> 4. Interface for overcome **Data persistence** issue

```
public interface MainActivityHelperInterface {
    void setData(ArrayList<Integer> dataSet);
    ArrayList<Integer> getData();

    void addEntry(int data);
    void removeEntry(int index);


}
```

Comment: Thanks for your response

Comment: Have you checked?

Comment: i am using this aprroach only but no luck

Comment: try to print data in logcat